# Why is setDetails empty, then data appears?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useGlobalContext } from "../context";

const SingleTvShow = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [details, setDetails] = useState({});
  const { imgUrl } = useGlobalContext();

  const getDetails = async (showId) => {
    const resp = await fetch(
      `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/${showId}?api_key=API_KEY&language=en-US`
    );
    const data = await resp.json();

    setDetails(data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getDetails(id);
  }, [id]);

  return (
    <div>
      {console.log(details)}
      <img src={imgUrl + details.backdrop_path} alt="show" />
    </div>
  );
};

export default SingleTvShow;
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FhYcJSqZiko0lJBoQdB2Gx5KyMWGR3dj/view?usp=sharing

I just started learning react, please help

Comment: The initial value is `{}` and after API request you're setting the state. `details` will be an empty object i.e initial value until the API request gets fulfilled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the initial value of state `details` is empty `{}`. `details` only update when you call api success. Before that, `details` kept the value `{}`

You can check like this:

```
{details.backdrop_path && <img src={imgUrl + details.backdrop_path} alt="show" />}
```

Comment: Okay, so what should I do?

Comment: What do you want?

Comment: Сheck the link, there is a screen of the error. How can I get rid of the error?

Comment: Load your image only after you have the data.

Answer (score 0):

As @Viet said - the initial value is an empty object `{}` that is being populated when you have fetched the data.

If you want to show the data to your UI *only* when the fetching process has been completed then i would suggest changing your return to this:

```js
return (
    <div>
      {console.log(details)}
      {details && <img src={imgUrl + details.backdrop_path} alt="show" /> }
    </div>
  );
```

This tells your function to only show the the `img` element if your state is not an empty object.